# How do I archive two objects using NSKeyedArchiever?

Tags: iphone, nskeyedarchiver

Previously, I have an array in which I use NSKeyedArchiver to archieve.

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:docPath];
```

Called on `applicationWillTerminate` and `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Upon starting up, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOPtions`, the array is unarchieved:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:docPath];
```

Everything was good. Since then, I added a Singleton class for Settings variables. I would like to archive the Singleton as well. How would I do that?

The part that confuses me is if I call the same message:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:singleton toFile:docPath];
```

How can the app know which object I want to unarchive when I call:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:docPath];
```

Is it the array or the singleton?

The archiveRootObject accepts an (id) which to me means whatever I want. I can create a data class which includes the array and the singleton. Is that how I am suppose to do this? Is there a better way? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to encode more than one object at the root level, you'll need to create the archiver using `+alloc` and `-initForWritingWithMutableData:` yourself, send it -encodeObject:forKey: messages for each of the objects you want to add to the archive, and finally `-finishEncoding`. You can then write the data to a file yourself.

It'll look something like this (*warning:* untested code ahead):

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

[archiver encodeObject:someObject forKey:@"people"];
[archiver encodeObject:anotherObject forKey:@"places"];
[archiver encodeObject:thirdObject forKey:@"things"];
[archiver finishEncoding];

[data writeToURL:someUrl atomically:YES];
[archiver release];
```

To retrieve the objects, you'll do essentially the opposite: read a file into an NSData object; create an NSKeyedUnarchiver with `+alloc` and `-initForReadingWithData:`; retrieve the objects you care about using `-decodeObjectForKey:`; and finally call `-finishDecoding`. You can almost read the sample above from bottom to top with a few name changes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to play around with it and I'll get back to you with what I got.

Comment: To unarchive, I have to do NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; then [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data]; I hope that will help someone.

Comment: I am able to archieve and unarchieve correctly but it seems like the Singleton class does not persist from app delegate. I've posted it as another SO question here:

Answer (score 3):

To be archivable, your singleton class must conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. You will have to implement its `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` methods.

Again if you do `archiveRootObject:toFile:` on two objects with the same file path then you will overwrite one of them. To encode two objects, you will have to do something like this,

```
NSData * data = [NSMutableData data];
NSKeyedArchiver * archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data]; 
[archiver encodeObject:array forKey:@"Array"];
[archiver encodeObject:singleton forKey:@"Singleton"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
BOOL result = [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[archiver release];
```

You can read more on archiving in this [`guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1).